# How can I change the root path in a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

In a .bat file, How can I change the root path to be c:\temp\code

Comment: A drive's root path is always "<drive>:\", by definition, and can't be changed. Do you mean "change the current directory"?

Comment: yes, change the current directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd /d c:\temp\code
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest `pushd` over `cd` in this case. That way you can restore the previous directory with `popd` at the end. Unless a batch file should actually change the path even after it has been run, I'd always restore it at the end of the batch:

```
@echo off
rem change current directory
pushd C:\Temp\Code
rem ...
rem something your batch needs to do
rem ...
rem restore old working directory
popd
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, doing `cd c:\temp\code` only doesn't work if you're in another drive. This way works all the time:

```
c:
cd c:\temp\code
```